# Issue with locαting HTML with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to learn Selenium for Python (3.4.0) and have had success with the basic things - installing, opening browser and web page, so on. But when I try to open a specific HTML form I am met with an error - something to do with the 'driver' at the beginning of the 'driver.find_element_by_name'.

My code is:

```
#vocab express logger onner

import selenium

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


browser=webdriver.Firefox()


browser.get("https://www.vocabexpress.com/login/")

uname = driver.find_element_by_name("uname")

uname.send_keys("13holmee")
```

and the error message is:

```
    uname = driver.find_element_by_name("uname")
NameError: name 'driver' is not defined
```

Sorry if this too simple a question or has been asked before (I couldn't find anything), I'm still new to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `driver` in your namespace, because you have not defined a variable with that name.

`find_element_by_name` is a method of the `webdriver.Firefox` object, which in this case you have named `browser`. Try `uname = browser.find_element_by_name("uname")`.